# Oracle 11gR2: Any DBMS_* package to kill session?

Tags: session, plsql, oracle11g, database

Is there any DBMS_* package contains session kill procedure/function?

Currently I'm using `execute immediate 'alter system kill session...` statement but maybe there is some package delivered out of the box contains procedure/function to kill session for `SID`, `SERIAL#` and (optionally if RAC is enabled) `INSTR_ID` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no package to do that.  If there was, it would almost certainly be mentioned in the [PL/SQL Packages and Types Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/toc.htm).

Specifically, I would expect it to be in the package `DBMS_SESSION`.  That package already has several procedures that are equivalent to SQL statements.  But nothing in there or the other packages will kill a specific session.